# Rewrite URL containing spaces

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have an url with the following format:
`domain/product.php?name=product a`

Now I need to rewrite this to:
`domain/product a` (including the space in the word) like:
`http://www.directline-holidays.co.uk/Costa Blanca`

How do I do this? The closest result I got so far is the following:
`domain/p/product-a`

With the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)/$ destination.php?name=$1
```

I could not even use the name without the "-". I need the product name just as it is in the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work: It will simply give you the rest of the URL string after the /p/ directory to the end of the string, which in your case should be the end of the URL, correct?

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ destination.php?name=$1
```

For the pages that are not product pages, if you know they will end in a .php file extension you can filter for those pages with the following rule:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(destination\.php).*$ 
 RewriteRule ^([^\.php]+)$ destination.php?name=$1
```

**EDIT:** Fixed for infinite loop condition by adding RewriteCond for destination.php

Comment: with the /p/product name format i already got it working, the issue is that i want only the product name after the domain name. without the /p

Comment: i see...so should just be: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ destination.php?name=$1

Comment: its redirecting everything to the destination.php page...need to have a check so that it does not redirect .php pages like domain/index.php, domain/contact-us.php etc pages to the destination pages...event only typing domain/ is getting redirected to the destination.php page...ny idea?

Comment: i even tried RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]*)$ destination.php?name=$1...but again object not found issue :(

Comment: @Kunal - check my edit for another suggestion on filtering for *.php files

Answer (score 2):

add "%20" to the URL, such as:

```
http://www.directline-holidays.co.uk/Costa%20Blanca
```

20 in hexadecimal base is the ASCII number for space.

Edit:

In addition to powtac's comment:

Use the JS encodeURIComponent() function to encode a value that should be used in a URL:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: If you use PHP to create the links add urlencode() around the link, it will add the %20 and other stuff automatically.

Comment: thanks, i have solved it already. now what i need is the rewrite rule which will allow me to make the url only with the product name. pls help.

Comment: @Kunal: Try the following REGEXP:

^[^/]$

Comment: You cannot have an URL with a space: what you provided (`domain/product.php?name=product a`) is not a valid URL. Using the proper form (`domain/product.php?name=product%20a`) will give what you want.

Comment: @Dor ur soln worked, but when i tried:
RewriteRule ^[^/]$ destination.php?id=$1

and the url:
http://localhost/zip2/test

it said object not found!

any idea?

Comment: The requirement isn't clear, but try: RewriteRule ([^/])$ destination.php?id=$1

Answer (score 1):

Try this rules..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule product-name-(.*)\.htm$ product.php?name=$1
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule product/name/(.*)/ product.php?name=$1
RewriteRule product/name/(.*) product.php?name=$1
```

Comment: I prefer to use the first one I wrote.. I had problems with the second one depending the server I use.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean if destination is a php file , doesn't rewirte it , else rewrite any thing to destination.php ? if so , this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ destination.php?name=$1
```