# PHP APACHE URL rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have been searching all over the web for a solid 2 hours now trying different things, and none of what i found would work.

I want to redirect to a non-existent folder and then convert that into a query-string - for example an anchor tag that leads to "domain.com/test/" But .htaccess should intercept that and change it into "domain.com/index.php?p=test" Behind the curtains without the viewer seeing the query-string

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I have tried pretty much everything on google - page 1 and two at least :P

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php apache url rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750884/php-apache-url-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite has attribute tests that allows you to test if the requested url is a file or a directory. See [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

To use this, you use a `RewriteCond` to test `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. You can then redirect or internally rewrite the url. A redirect will change the url visibly for the client, while an internal redirect will only show a different page without actually changing the url.

```
#The requested url is NOT a directory AND NOT a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

If you want an external redirect to happen, add the `R`-flag. The `R=301` flag will make the redirect permanent, but only make it permanent if all rules work as you expect them to work.

Comment: Okay i have tried this and i can go to /Test/p/Home and alike but all the relative links are broken aswell as the sql functions - So I am not sure I am liking this correctly...

PS. /Test is the folder in my domain root

Want to display this "http://localhost:8888/Test/Home" in the URL but php should interpret it as http://localhost:8888/Test/?p=Home

Comment: Try to use `RewriteBase /Test/`. mod_rewrite doesn't change links on the page, so if relative links are broken, you must have changed something else.

Comment: Okay Well it works I just had to not use /p/Home as I was trying...
Is there a way to detect what it uses? so eg. ?p=Home will go to /Home And /refresh=213124123 will go to /refresh/213124123? or something like that - basically detect which querystring is called :)

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$` with `%1` as replacement and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=(.*)$` with `%1` and `%2` as replacements. Read the documentation and search for examples on how to use them.

Comment: I am not sure how that works - apache and regex is the things i am having a very hard time learning sadly :/ would you be able to prove the entire code? because when i look for examples, I always manage to screw them up somehow :P

Comment: Make a new question and do at least some trial and error first. Figure out what exactly RewriteCond does. Figure out what the difference is between `$1` and `%1`. Figure out what RewriteRule does and how it is affected by RewriteCond. For regex, find the documentation on (I believe) preg regex. Then find an online tool and experiment with the syntax, see what it matches and what it doesn't match. You'll learn nothing by simply copying and pasting code.

Comment: Trust me - I have tried to get this to work for a couple of hours and I have tried to learn regex before, with an online tool - but it just messes with my head...

The thing is -I actually learn from copy-pasting, as I don't just copy-paste but I experiment with it afterwards :)